# What are Benchmarking Best Practices for US Census Data

Tags: r, geocoding, acs, census, tidycensus

I’m working with a dataset that crosses 2020 with data from 2015-2022. What is the best practice for geocoding within a dataset that spans two census' and multiple ACS years.

Should I be benchmarking to look at a single year snapshot for each ACS product/year or should I be benchmarking on the decennial census alone for Pre 2020 (2010) and post 2020?

I know that boundaries change between decennial census’ and when going to connect to tract level ACS data I will want to have the correct tract for correct 5 year estimates I’m going to get.

For those who are curious my code for 2021 results is [here](https://github.com/MattResner/Mayors-Action-Center-Service-Requests/blob/master/Mayors%20Action%20Center%20Project%20Streamlined.R) though likely not required for answering the question.

Thanks,
Rez

Comment: Are you asking us to advise on how to do this research? Or are you asking for finding different APIs or how to connect/use specific APIs?

Comment: The question is unclear, what do you mean by benchmarking? Can you provide an example? Also, have you looked at the [`tidycensus`](https://walker-data.com/tidycensus/) package?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

US Census got back with me after two weeks:

"American Community Survey (ACS) data uses boundaries from the last year of the 5-year estimate. Therefore, the 2015-2022 dataset will use 2020 tract boundaries (tracts are only updated every 10 years). It will therefore be consistent with your 2020 Decennial Census data."